# How to TAIL & EGREP for a specified time range in a BASH script

Tags: apache-2.2, grep, tail, alternative-php-cache, segmentation-fault

The subject mostly says it all. I am in charge of a few web servers running Ubuntu 12.04 running Apache2 & I would like to setup APC.

Now I understand APC can hit segmentation fault issues when acting on PHP code that has errors or quirks. So cleanup is advisable, but not really practical for a manpower standpoint.

So I have cooked up a script to monitor the main Apache2 `error.log` & count how many segmentation faults it sees. I run it as a cron job that runs every 2 minutes. If it hits a specified number of segmentation faults, it should automatically restart Apache2 to clear out APC & get services running smoothly again. The seed idea of this script [comes from a comment on this page](http://2bits.com/articles/logwatcher-restart-apache-after-a-segmentation-fault.html) but I have really heavily built upon the concept to make it more production ready for my needs & tastes.

I am generally happy with this script, but feel one major improvement is the core logic in this snippet:

```
if [[ `tail -n ${TAIL_NUMLINES} "${APACHE_ERROR_LOG}" | egrep -c "${TEXT_TO_WATCH}"` -ge ${FAIL_COUNT} ]]; then
```

That is basically the core logic that tails the log file for a specified number of lines, and if it sees a specified number of log entries with `exit signal Segmentation fault` in them, then it decides it's time to do something. In this case, log the incident, e-mail someone about the incident & restart Apache.

I would like that logic to factor in time because errors can be few & far between.  So there are cases where my `FAIL_COUNT` simply matches the `TAIL_NUMLINES` despite a restart because no new entries are in the main error log because no new errors have hit.  Which would end up in a situation where the server basically restarts every time the cron job hits. Which is horrible.

So my stop-gap solution for now is to set `FAIL_COUNT` & `TAIL_NUMLINES` to a low enough number to match the standard counts of entries that are created when Apache2 reloads.  But I still don't like that.

So what—if anything—can be done to add a time frame to my `tail`/`egrep` logic.  Also, I would like to avoid creating a timestamp or log line position hint being saved to a file if possible. I want this script to be self-contained other than depending on the cron job.

Full script as I have it now.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOCK_NAME="APACHE_LOGWATCHER"
LOCK_DIR=/tmp/${LOCK_NAME}.lock
PID_FILE=${LOCK_DIR}/${LOCK_NAME}.pid

DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
TIME=`date +%H%M`
# SUFFIX="-"${DATE}"-"${TIME};
SUFFIX="-"${DATE};

APACHE_ERROR_LOG="/var/log/apache2/error.log"
APACHE_RESTART="/etc/init.d/apache2 restart"
TEXT_TO_WATCH="exit signal Segmentation fault"

HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
MAIL_ADDRESS="myname@domain.name.here.com"
MAIL_SUBJECT=${HOSTNAME}": Apache Segfault Notification"

SCRIPT_NAME=$(basename "$0")
SCRIPT_BASE_NAME=${SCRIPT_NAME%.*}

LOG_DIR="/opt/segfault_logs/"
LOG_FILENAME=${SCRIPT_BASE_NAME}${SUFFIX}".log"
LOG_FULLPATH=${LOG_DIR}${LOG_FILENAME}

TAIL_NUMLINES=5
FAIL_COUNT=4

# If the Apache log file doesn't exist, then exit.
if [ ! -f ${APACHE_ERROR_LOG} ]; then
    exit
fi

# Main process.
if mkdir ${LOCK_DIR} 2>/dev/null; then
    # If the ${LOCK_DIR} doesn't exist, then start working & store the ${PID_FILE}
    echo $$ > ${PID_FILE}

    STARTUP_MESSAGE="`date` Log watcher starting."
    if [ -d ${LOG_DIR} ]; then
        echo ${STARTUP_MESSAGE} >> ${LOG_FULLPATH}
    fi

    # Tail--but do not follow--a chunk of the LOG_FULLPATH if the number of instances is
    # greater than or equal to the FAIL_COUNT, act
    if [[ `tail -n ${TAIL_NUMLINES} "${APACHE_ERROR_LOG}" | egrep -c "${TEXT_TO_WATCH}"` -ge ${FAIL_COUNT} ]]; then

        # Create the log message.
        LOG_MESSAGE="`date` Segfault detected on "$HOSTNAME

        # Log the error to the file.
        if [ -d ${LOG_DIR} ]; then
            echo ${LOG_MESSAGE} >> ${LOG_FULLPATH}
        fi

        # Send e-mail notification.
        echo ${LOG_MESSAGE}$'\n\r'${FAIL_COUNT} | mail -s "${MAIL_SUBJECT}" ${MAIL_ADDRESS}

        # Restart Apache
        ${APACHE_RESTART}
    fi

    rm -rf ${LOCK_DIR}
    exit
else
    if [ -f ${PID_FILE} ] && kill -0 $(cat ${PID_FILE}) 2>/dev/null; then
        # Confirm that the process file exists & a process
        # with that PID is truly running.
        # echo "Running [PID "$(cat ${PID_FILE})"]" >&2
        exit
    else
        # If the process is not running, yet there is a PID file--like in the case
        # of a crash or sudden reboot--then get rid of the ${LOCK_DIR}
        rm -rf ${LOCK_DIR}
        exit
    fi
fi
```

**EDIT:** Here is an example of the Apache2 logfile output the above script is monitoring.

```
[Sat Mar 02 14:32:26 2013] [notice] child pid 14696 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sat Mar 02 14:32:27 2013] [notice] child pid 13914 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sat Mar 02 14:32:27 2013] [notice] child pid 15735 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sat Mar 02 14:32:28 2013] [notice] child pid 14865 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sat Mar 02 14:32:28 2013] [notice] child pid 15545 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sat Mar 02 14:32:30 2013] [notice] child pid 13821 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sat Mar 02 14:32:31 2013] [notice] child pid 15683 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sat Mar 02 14:32:47 2013] [notice] child pid 15684 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sat Mar 02 14:33:54 2013] [notice] child pid 15482 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sat Mar 02 14:34:04 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Mar 02 14:34:06 2013] [notice] ModSecurity for Apache/2.6.3 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Sat Mar 02 14:34:06 2013] [notice] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.4.6"; loaded version="1.4.6"
[Sat Mar 02 14:34:06 2013] [notice] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.12"; loaded version="8.12 2011-01-15"
[Sat Mar 02 14:34:06 2013] [notice] ModSecurity: LUA compiled version="Lua 5.1"
[Sat Mar 02 14:34:06 2013] [notice] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.7.8"
[Sat Mar 02 14:34:07 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: Would you be willing to write a line to the logfile? I think this can be simplified greatly if you wrote a marker to say "read up until here", then read the file backwards from the bottom (so to be efficient when the file is huge) until you hit that line, then count the number of segfaults in between.

Comment: Hmmm… That is actually not a bad idea. If you could write an answer with a simple example that could be included in my code, I will consider this suggestion a contender for an answer since this seems to be more intricate than a simple `tail`/`egrep` as I have in my coding.

Comment: Will you accept Python? I'm not convinced bash is the right tool for the job here.

Comment: Sorry Jay, but I don’t consider an answer other than a `bash` solution to be a appropriate. I know there has to be a `bash` based answer that can work.  I might even have one myself once my brain recovers a bit ;)

Comment: That's fine, I thought I would ask anyway. Here's another thought: how about just counting the number of segfaults since the last restart?

Comment: Again, if you have a practical solution then please provide it as a practical answer. Simply saying, “You should do this.” is not helping. My whole script is there. Just redo it to achieve these goals if you feel they will work.

Comment: I don't know the problem as well as you do, so it's easier if I just suggest an idea and you tell me whether it would work, since it'll save me a whole lot of time coding it if the basis is flawed. That's why I suggested it.

Comment: @Jay, I have seen some painfully lazy questions posted here.  My question explains the scenario, gives one the script—that hopefully can save the headaches of others—and now I have added the log files.  I see your answer, but honestly it doesn't seem you really want to provide a practical answer that uses the examples I provide.

Comment: This is exactly why I *asked you* if you liked the idea. The idea was simple: count the number of segmentation faults in between Apache restarts. If you don't like it, don't use it, but that's all you're getting from me with that attitude. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [`logtail`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logtail).  The purpose of `logtail` is to remember where you got up to when reading a file last time so you can start again at that point next time.

Use it like this:

```
logtail -o /tmp/apache.offset ${APACHE_ERROR_LOG} | egrep -c "${TEXT_TO_WATCH}"
```

Comment: I like this concept. But still feel queasy about the whole `/tmp/apache.offset` as well as the fact that logtail is not standardized across installs.

Answer (score 0):

This demonstrates my idea

#### should_restart.sh

```
last_restart_line_number=$( grep restart sample_log_file.txt -n | tail -1 | cut -f1 -d: )
segfaults_since_restart=$( tail -n +$last_restart_line_number sample_log_file.txt | grep segfault -c )

if [ $segfaults_since_restart -gt 5 ]; then
    echo "Yes, restart apache"
else
    echo "No, don't restart apache"
fi
```

#### sample_log_file.txt

```
segfault
segfault
segfault
restart
segfault
segfault
segfault
restart
segfault
segfault
segfault
restart
segfault
segfault
segfault
segfault
```